# Table Formatting Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, formatting

I'm having trouble with this program. I can't seem to figure out how to get the first number of the year(notice the first year is missing). I also formatted my while loop to end at zero but I still get the -20.82 and undefined at the bottom of the table. Lastly, I've looked all over but I can't find the correct formula to calculate I feel like I've almost got it but I'm missing a vital piece. Please help!

```
function displayWelcome() {
var welcome = "This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.";
return welcome;
}
function calculateMinimumPayment(bal, intr) {
var min = bal * intr;
return min;
}
function displayPayments(bal, intr, min) {
var top1 = "Balance on your credit card: " + bal + "\nInterest Rate: " + intr + "\nAssuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)\nYour minimum payment would be $" + min;
var top2 = "PAYOFF SCHEDULE\n\n______________\nYear\tBalance\t\tPayment Num\tInterest Paid\n";
console.log(top1);
console.log(top2);
var yearcount = 0;
var year = 1;
var paynum = 0;
while (bal >= 0) {
    paynum++;
    yearcount++;
    bal = (bal+(intr-min));
    intrp = intr+(bal*min);
    var tbl1 = parseFloat(bal).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + paynum + "\t\t" + parseFloat(intrp).toFixed(2);
    var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
    if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
        year = year+1;
        var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
    } else {
        tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
    }
    console.log(tbl2);
}
}
console.log(displayWelcome());
console.log(displayPayments(1500,0.18,calculateMinimumPayment(1500, 0.02)));
```

Here's the output:

```
This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and interest paid
based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.
Balance on your credit card: 1500
Interest Rate: 0.18
Assuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)
Your minimum payment would be $30
PAYOFF SCHEDULE

______________
Year    Balance         Payment Num     Interest Paid

        1470.18         1               44105.58
        1440.36         2               43210.98
        1410.54         3               42316.38
        1380.72         4               41421.78
        1350.90         5               40527.18
        1321.08         6               39632.58
        1291.26         7               38737.98
        1261.44         8               37843.38
        1231.62         9               36948.78
        1201.80         10              36054.18
        1171.98         11              35159.58
 2      1142.16         12              34264.98
        1112.34         13              33370.38
        1082.52         14              32475.78
        1052.70         15              31581.18
        1022.88         16              30686.58
        993.06          17              29791.98
        963.24          18              28897.38
        933.42          19              28002.78
        903.60          20              27108.18
        873.78          21              26213.58
        843.96          22              25318.98
        814.14          23              24424.38
 3      784.32          24              23529.78
        754.50          25              22635.18
        724.68          26              21740.58
        694.86          27              20845.98
        665.04          28              19951.38
        635.22          29              19056.78
        605.40          30              18162.18
        575.58          31              17267.58
        545.76          32              16372.98
        515.94          33              15478.38
        486.12          34              14583.78
        456.30          35              13689.18
 4      426.48          36              12794.58
        396.66          37              11899.98
        366.84          38              11005.38
        337.02          39              10110.78
        307.20          40              9216.18
        277.38          41              8321.58
        247.56          42              7426.98
        217.74          43              6532.38
        187.92          44              5637.78
        158.10          45              4743.18
        128.28          46              3848.58
        98.46           47              2953.98
 5      68.64           48              2059.38
        38.82           49              1164.78
        9.00            50              270.18
        -20.82          51              -624.42
undefined
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you reduce your code down to that which doesn't work? Or only show the minimum code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are two problems.

**Printing the year on the first row**. If you put the `yearcount++` at the beginning of the loop, when you get to the conditional it values 1, so it doesn't print. Put the `yearcount` as the last line of the loop.

**Not printing a negative value at the end**. You check if `bal>=0` in the while condition, but short after that you substract 29.82 points from it and then you print. On the last iteration bal equals 9, then substract 29.82 and it becomes -20.82 and then you print it.

To fix this one you should check if `bal-(int-min) >= 0`.

I think this should fix both problems:

```
while (bal+(intr-min) >= 0) {
    paynum++;
    bal = (bal+(intr-min));
    intrp = intr+(bal*min);
    var tbl1 = parseFloat(bal).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + paynum + "\t\t" + parseFloat(intrp).toFixed(2);
    if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
        year = year+1;
        var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
    } else {
        var tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
    }
    yearcount++;
    console.log(tbl2);
}
```

Comment: This fixes the year problem but I still get an undefined at the end of the table.

Comment: That's strange, I don't get any `undefined` when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Try this:

```
function displayWelcome() {
return "This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.";

}
function calculateMinimumPayment(bal, intr) {
var min = bal * intr;
return min;
}
function displayPayments(bal, intr, min) {
debugger;
var top1 = "Balance on your credit card: " + bal + "\nInterest Rate: " + intr + "\nAssuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)\nYour minimum payment would be $" + min;
var top2 = "PAYOFF SCHEDULE\n\n______________\nYear\tBalance\t\tPayment Num\tInterest Paid\n";
console.log(top1);
console.log(top2);
var yearcount = 0;
var year = 1;
var paynum = 0;
while (bal >= 0) {
    paynum++;
    yearcount++;
    bal = (bal+(intr-min));
    if(bal <= 0){
    break;
    }
    intrp = intr+(bal*min);
    var tbl1 = parseFloat(bal).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + paynum + "\t\t" + parseFloat(intrp).toFixed(2);
    var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
    if (yearcount % 12 === 0 || year == 1) {
        var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
        year++;
    } else {
        tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
    }
    console.log(tbl2);
}
}
debugger;
console.log(displayWelcome());
displayPayments(1500,0.18,calculateMinimumPayment(1500, 0.02));
```

Comment: The 1 in the Year column is still missing!

Comment: remove debuggers )